# Setting __local float in OpenCL

Tags: opencl

Im trying to set new __local float but I get error when I pass the size of the float as argument.

This code gives error:

```
int TILE_DIM = get_local_size(0)*get_local_size(1);  //local size
__local float buffer[TILE_DIM];
```

This code does not:

```
int TILE_DIM = get_local_size(0)*get_local_size(1); //local size
__local float buffer[512];
```

Answer (score 2):

Local memory must always be allocated before the kernel runs. Therefore, no arrays with kernel runtime length are possible. However, you can pass a pointer to (uninitialised) `__local` memory as an argument to the kernel. The length of this can be set in the [clSetKernelArg()](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clSetKernelArg.html) call. (Check the linked documentation for details on local memory kernel arguments.) So it's variable-length per enqueued kernel, but not per workgroup.

Answer (score 2):

The size of the `__local` array can be passed to [clBuildProgram](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clBuildProgram.html) in `options` argument: `"-DTILE_DIM=512"`

For example:
`clBuildProgram(program, 1, &device.device_id, "-DTILE_DIM=512", NULL, NULL);`

This way the size of the local array can be decided at kernel build time.